# Where did Darkwing Duck make his money?

Tags: disney, darkwing-duck

Maybe I missed something, but what does Drake do in ordinary life? Maybe S.H.U.S.H finance him?

Comment: On several occasions it's shown that he's independently wealthy and/or holds various jobs; https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing_Duck_(character)

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but how this money is enough for the maintenance of its vast arsenal, the payment of gasoline for an airplane and a motorcycle, the maintenance of the Gosalyn, and so on?

Comment: It's different in different properties. In some he appears to be an employee of SHUSH. In others, he seems to be little more than a hired gun/private detective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to his [character page](https://darkwingduck.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing_Duck_(character)) and the [Disney comics page](https://darkwingduck.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing_Duck_(Disney_Comics)) on the Darkwing Duck wiki in the original series:

> Drake Mallard has no occupation outside of Darkwing Duck and he receives payment for it from SHUSH.

and

> Darkwing also sometimes lends his special talents to the ultra-secret intelligence organization known as SHUSH, which provides him with a sizable paycheck and the latest crimefighting technology.

However, in the new [DuckTales](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing_Duck_(character)#DuckTales_.282017.29) series:

> This incarnation of Darkwing is the fictional star of a superhero television show, instead of someone who actually exists in the show's universe. He is played by an actor named Jim Starling, who is known for performing his own stunts.

...

> However, the showrunner of DuckTales hinted at Darkwing existing as a real character within the show's universe, with the "show-within-a-show" being a fictional depiction of the real Darkwing's exploits. This is supported by the fact that F.O.W.L. and S.H.U.S.H. and the city of St. Canard all exist in the show's universe.

Comment: In at least one comic serial, he goes and works for [Quackwerks](https://darkwingduck.fandom.com/wiki/Quackwerks_Corporation)

Comment: So he gets [SHUSH money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hush_money)?